# How do I unpublish my tor exit node?

Tags: exit-relays

I ran a tor exit node on the wrong network.
Which I realized after a couple of days, after I kept getting CAPTCHAs on Cloudflare.

Also quite annoying that several sites that I use stopped working because of CORS errors
(strict-origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin) which is also because of cloudflare.

I shut it down a few days ago but I'm still listed on

https://check.torproject.org/exit-addresses
https://check.torproject.org/torbulkexitlist

Anyway to remove my entry?